# Looking to Add a variable inside an HTML link

Tags: javascript, html

excuse my ignorance but i would really appreciate your help.

I am new to HTML and i am just trying to add a variable inside an HTML link (ex. http://www.google.com/**variable**/).

The variable will be text type and i want to replace the text when i type something in a search bar.

(ex. search for "cars" and have www.google.com/cars)

Any thoughts how i can start this? 
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write following javascript function:

```
   function set(me)
    {
        var link = 'http://www.google.com/';
        document.getElementById('result').value = link + me.value;
    }
```

I have written following HTML lines to illustrate:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="test" onkeyup="set(this);" />
    <input type="text" id="result" />
</div>
```

You can call this function on onkeyup or onchange events as required.

Answer (score 0):

Include in your Html.

```html
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
 <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search in Google" />
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
     <input type="checkbox" name="sitesearch" value="rotinadigital.net"/>Only my site<br />
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables in strings then take a look at [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You can use them like so:

```
var variable = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var url = `https://www.google.com/${variable}/`;
// same as 'https://www.google.com/' + variable + '/'
```

It sounds like you're trying to achieve an effect similar to Google Instant though. Afaik that's just done through standard [anchor links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page) and using javascript to (rather radically) manipulate the contents of the page. Actually navigating to a different page would cause a rather noticeable delay.